# Unable to run "INSERT INTO" from Azure SQL external table

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, sharding, external-tables

In my Azure SQL DB I have an external table - let's call this `tableName_origData` - and I have another table which we'll refer to as `tableName`.

`tableName` was created using a generated `CREATE` script from `tableName_origData` (in its original location) so I can be sure that all the column types are identical.

However, when I run

```
INSERT INTO tableName (
    [list of column names]
)
SELECT
    [same list of column names]
FROM
    tableName_origData
```

I encounter the following exception:

> Large object column support is limited to only nvarchar(max) data
>   type.

As far as my understanding of Azure SQL's data types goes, I don't have anything larger than NVARCHAR(MAX). Furthermore, the message implies that NVARCHAR(MAX) *is* supported (and I can see that the same script works on other tables which contain NVARCHAR(MAX).

Can anyone better explain the cause of this exception and what I might need to do in order to insert its data into an identical table?

Here is a list of all the column types used in the table(s):

`BIGINT` x 3
`NCHAR(20)` x 1
`NVARCHAR(45)` x 5
`NVARCHAR(100)` x 14
`NVARCHAR(MAX)` x 10

Answer (score 1):

External tables is read-only. The developer can select data, but cannot perform any form of DML-processing

To solve this issue please use this technique:

https://technology.amis.nl/2005/04/05/updateable-external-tables/

Warn: Unless for the simplest of uses, we do not recommend using this technique for any serious application

Comment: Please expand on that link in your answer. Link-only answers are not good answers as the link might be moved or removed in the future. Please read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/273645) on *"Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?"*.

Comment: the referance url  for Oracle Database. I think this is not answer